# In this conditional JSX rendering, why is a double (!!) required?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In the following JSX

Why is there a double !

```js
{!! count && <div className={'styles.info'}>{`did this ${count}`}</div>}
```

Comment: its casting `count` to a boolean.

Comment: Remember "Bang, bang! You're boolean now!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the space between `!!` and `count`. They should be together like so: `!!count`.

Like the comment said, it is coercing the value to a boolean. If `count` is a falsey value, say `0`, it would still be rendered by React. Using `!!` to coerce `0` to `false`, would guarantee that `0` is never rendered.